# p:selectOneMenu outline gets extra space when nested in p:panel

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using PrimeFaces 5.2 and I have a `p:selectOneMenu` inside a `p:panel`. If the `selectOneMenu` is outside of the panel the issue does not persist, but when inside the panel it looks like this:

[image: selectOneMenu in panel]

You can see the distortion on the right side of the `selectOneMenu`.

I tried some CSS editing but it doesn't seem to help:

```
.ui-selectonemenu-panel{
    width: 150px;
}
.ui-selectonemenu-panel .ui-selectonemenu-items-wrapper{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Setting width to 150px in `.ui-selectonemenu-panel` only helped restore the dropdown menu's size, not the distorted part itself.

Changing `selectOneMenu` width from the xhtml file doesn't fix the issue. The theme I used is a PrimeFaces theme called "bootstrap" but resizing the theme doesn't work as well. I didn't try different themes because I'd like to keep using this theme.

This is the way the `selectOneMenu` should look:

[image]

I couldn't find anything on the web similar to this issue. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Cannot reproduce with default theme but try also changing width of following classes: `ui-selectonemenu-label` `ui-selectonemenu`

Comment: @Geinmachi Thanks for your useful comment, please see my answer for further details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to Geinmachi's comment. Changing `ui-selectonemenu-label` seems to work.

Originally my `selectOneMenu` has a 150px width and I edited `ui-selectonemenu-label` like this in my CSS file at first:

```
.ui-selectonemenu-label{
    width: 80px !important;
}
```

And every my `selectOneMenu`s started to look like this:

[image]

You can see the gray area on the right side caused by the shrinked label. And when I make the width 200px it looks like this:

[image]

But when I set the label width to 150px I observe the same extra space as pictured in my question. So I tried to set it to 120px and it looks fixed. I think the gray dropdown button on the right side has around 30px width thus setting the label width without respecting that 30px difference causes extra space by overflowing beyond the `selectOneMenu`.

However, I still don't know why the extra space only occurred when `selectOneMenu` was nested in a panel.

Comment: _"However, I still don't know why the extra space only occurred when selectOneMenu was nested in a panel."_ Use a browser developer tool to see what classes/style are applied compared to default.

Comment: @Kukeltje there's a `ui-panel` class applied to panels and it applies a `padding: 0.2em` value by default. I think it might be the culprit.